# git pushing to multiple remote repositories

Tags: git, version-control, repository, push

I have a project I've cloned from Heroku which currently is my origin.

Among origin, I have an additional remote GitHub repo aliased GitHub, and a Heroku remote repo for staging aliased stage.

Running

```
git remote
```

yields

```
github
origin
stage
```

How can I follow a workflow of working on local changes (usually GitHub/develop branch)
and then have the ability to push to GitHub/master, stage/master, or origin/master
when I can only stage a given commit once and push it to one branch?

If I pushed to say GitHub/develop, then wanted to push the changes I made in GitHub/develop to stage/master, how would I go about this?

What is the typical workflow for this type of scenario of wanting to push changes to multiple remote repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I've already pushed my changes here to github/develop and now
>   I want to push them to stage/master?

```
git push stage develop:master -f
```

Above command will force push your local develop branch as master, as heroku compiles its slug from master you'll see the changes in your app. This might be useful when you want to test changes to a specific branch without merging to origin's master.

However I'll suggest you a different workflow. Create a new branch to push changes to staging server. Let's say its currentQA. Before deploying pull any changes from
master, currentQA and your branch.

eg. At work we have a currentQA branch. whenever we need to deploy anything on staging we merge our branch to currentQA and force push it on staging as master.

let's say the branch I am working on is someImportantFix:

```
#push the changes of my branch to origin
git push origin someImportantFix

#switch to currentQA
git checkout currentQA

#pull any changes in the master branch
git pull origin master

#pull any changes in the currentQA branch
git pull origin currentQA

#pull the changes from my branch
git pull origin someImportantFix

#push the changes to origin
git push origin currentQA

#force push and deploy on heroku
git push staging currentQA:master -f
```

This might look tedious but helps a lot when you are working with a team.

We have three remotes for our project:

1. origin - github
2. staging - staging heroku
3. production - production heroku

We only deploy to master branch of staging and production.

Answer (score 0):

From github/develop tree you do
    git push staging develop:master

You can choose the remote and branch when pushing.

Comment: What if I'm from the origin (Heroku) tree? Also what if I've already pushed my changes here to github/develop and now I want to push them to stage/master?

Answer (score 0):

Question: What if I've already pushed my changes here to github/develop and now I want to push them to stage/master?

Answer: `git push stage master`

Comment: It says Everything up-to-date, yet when I visit the application my changes are not present

Comment: How can I merge one remote branch into another remote branch? IE github/develop into stage/master